# mysql results error on php

Tags: php, mysql

hello below is my code for a query with submit from..  the no of rows are correctly count and show in the page and the result rows are not show in my page and show "No results found, please search again", i cant find the error on my code, can anyone help to find it..

```
<?
    ### DEBUG
    $debugP = 0 ;
    ### END DEBUG

    include 'db_connector.php';
    require_once('myfunctions.php');


    include('header.php');

    #defauts

    $maxRows_p = 10;
    $pageNum_p = 0;
    if (isset($_GET['pageNum_p'])) {
      $pageNum_p = $_GET['pageNum_p'];
    }
    $startRow_p = $pageNum_p * $maxRows_p;
    $limit = ' LIMIT '.$startRow_p.', '.$maxRows_p;


        ## Start building sql for GET varables for advanced search

        ###Add city
        if(isset($_REQUEST['city']) && ($_REQUEST['city'] != ''))
            $search[] = ' city = "'.$_REQUEST['city'].'"';
        ###Add State
        if(isset($_REQUEST['district']) && ($_REQUEST['district'] != ''))
            $search[] = ' district = "'.$_REQUEST['district'].'"';
        ###Add lot size
        if(isset($_REQUEST['lot_size']) && ($_REQUEST['lot_size'] != ''))
            $search[] = ' perches >= '.$_REQUEST['lot_size'];

        $search[] = ' availibility = "0" ';
        ###implode to search string on ' and ';
        $searchStr = @implode(' and ',$search);


        $sql = 'select * FROM properties WHERE status="1" and'; ###status=1 and
        $sql .= $searchStr;

        ###Add column sorting
        if($_REQUEST['sort'] != '')
            $sort = ' order by added asc ';
        else
            $sort = $_REQUEST['sort'];


        ### DEBUG
        if($debugP) echo 'Advanced Search Sql<hr>'.$sql;

        $error['Results'] = 'No results found, please search again';

    ###}


    ### Finished Building search sql and execting #####
    $sql_with_limit = $sql . $sort . $limit;


    if($debugP)
        echo "<hr>Property Search with Limit SQL: $sql_with_limit";     

    ###Perform search
    $searchResults = mysql_query($sql.$sql_with_limit);

    ### BUILD OUTPUT ####

    if (isset($_GET['totalRows_p'])) {
      $totalRows_p = $_GET['totalRows_p'];
    } else {
      if($debugP)
          echo "<hr>Property with out limit SQL: $sql $sort";
      $all_p = mysql_query($sql.$sort);
      $totalRows_p = mysql_num_rows($all_p);

      if($debugP)
          echo "<br>Result Rows $totalRows_p";
    }
    $totalPages_p = ceil($totalRows_p/$maxRows_p)-1;


    if($debugP)
        echo "<hr>Builting Query String for Limit: ";

    ###Build query string
    foreach($_GET as $name => $value){
        if($name != "pageNum_p")
            $queryString_p .= "&$name=$value";
    }

    if($debugP)
        echo $queryString_p;


?>
<div align="left" class="locText">Home<span class="locArrow">&nbsp;>&nbsp;</span> Search Results</div>
<hr size="1" color="#666666">
<table border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <?php if ($pageNum_p > 0) { ### Show if not first page ?>
      < href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_p=%d%s", $currentPage, 0, $queryString_p); ?>" class="pageLink">First</a> | 
      <?php } ### Show if not first page ?>
      <?php if ($pageNum_p > 0) { ### Show if not first page ?>
      < href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_p=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_p - 1), $queryString_p); ?>" class="pageLink">Previous</a> | 
      <?php } ### Show if not first page ?>
      <?php if ($pageNum_p < $totalPages_p) { ### Show if not last page ?>
      < href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_p=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_p, $pageNum_p + 1), $queryString_p); ?>" class="pageLink">Next</a> | 
      <?php } ### Show if not last page ?>
      <?php if ($pageNum_p < $totalPages_p) { ### Show if not last page ?>
      < href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_p=%d%s", $currentPage, $totalPages_p, $queryString_p); ?>" class="pageLink">Last</a>
      <?php } ### Show if not last page ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td class="pageText" >Showing: <strong><?php echo ($startRow_p + 1) ?> to <?php echo min($startRow_p + $maxRows_p, $totalRows_p) ?> of <?php echo $totalRows_p ?></strong> Listings</td>
          <td align="right" class="pageText"></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="5">xx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" class="resBorder">
        <tr>
          <td class="colText">Address</td>
          <td class="colText">City</td>
          <td class="colText">ST</td>
          <td class="colText">Price</td>
          <td class="colText">Beds</td>
          <td class="colText">Baths</td>
          <td class="colText">Sqft</td>
        </tr>
    <?php while($row_p = @mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResults)) { ?>
        <tr valign="top">
          <td class="bodytext"><?php echo $row_p['address']; ?></td>
          <td class="bodytext"><?php echo $row_p['city']; ?></td>
          <td class="bodytext"><?php echo $row_p['district']; ?></td>
          <td class="bodytext"><?php echo Money($row_p['price'],1); ?></td>
          <td class="bodytext"><?php echo $row_p['rooms']; ?></td>
          <td class="bodytext">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="bodytext"><?php echo $row_p['floor']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        </table></td>
        </tr>
    <? } ?>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="5">xx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td class="pageText">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<? 
    ## if no results where found
    if(@mysql_num_rows($searchResults)<=0){
        foreach($error as $name => $value)
            print '<div align=center class="error">'.$name . ': ' . $value.'</div>';
    }
    ##Fetch Footer

?>
<script>
document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

Comment: HORRIBLE, highly insecure code. :(

Comment: ... so, is there a production server out there we can test this code on? :)

On a more serious note, you really should **at least** escape user input with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do here: `mysql_query($sql.$sql_with_limit)`? `$sql_with_limit` already contains `$sql`. Just see a couple of lines above `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
###Perform search
$searchResults = mysql_query($sql.$sql_with_limit);
```

To:

```
###Perform search
$searchResults = mysql_query($sql_with_limit);
```

Comment: yes its works.. results showing correct manner according to search quiery but nw another problem here.. whn i navigate thriough the results like next previous pages the search results will changed and to showing correctly as a ex.. wehn i search with city id 1, initially show only records belongs to city id 1, when i cclick next page the results changed to all cities and shows all records.. how can i changed this??